# Don't run tasks if lint fails with Gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp, task, lint

I have a few Gulp tasks...

```
gulp.task('checkScssSyntax', function() {
    return gulp.src(scssFiles)
        .pipe(sassLint())
        .pipe(sassLint.format());
});

gulp.task('checkJavascriptSyntax', function() {
  var jsStream = gulp.src(jsFiles);
  return jsStream.pipe(jsHint())
    .pipe(jsHint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    runSequence(['checkJavascriptSyntax', 'checkScssSyntax'], function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        runSequence('compileJS', 'compileCSS', 'watch');
      }
    });
});
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Gulp simply runs the second `runSequence` regardless of what happens.

I would like Gulp to only run the second sequence of tasks only if there are no warnings, and no errors in either of the syntax checks. I would also like to avoid outputting ANYTHING to the console other than what the linters print to the console.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkScssSyntax` and `checkJavascriptSyntax` tasks don't emit error events, so `run-sequence` doesn't notice when one of them has failed. Both `gulp-sass-lint` and `gulp-jshint` don't emit error events by default, but provide functions that instruct them to do so.

In your `checkScssSyntax` task use [`sassLint.failOnError()`](https://github.com/sasstools/gulp-sass-lint#sasslintfailonerror):

```
gulp.task('checkScssSyntax', function() {
    return gulp.src(scssFiles)
        .pipe(sassLint())
        .pipe(sassLint.format())
        .pipe(sassLint.failOnError());
});
```

In your `checkJavascriptSyntax` task use [`jsHint.reporter('fail')`](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint#fail-reporter):

```
gulp.task('checkJavascriptSyntax', function() {
  var jsStream = gulp.src(jsFiles);
  return jsStream.pipe(jsHint())
    .pipe(jsHint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(jsHint.reporter('fail'));
});
```

> I would also like to avoid outputting ANYTHING to the console other than what the linters print to the console

Gulp has a [CLI flag](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md#flags) that let's you suppress all gulp logging:

```
gulp --silent
```